# Sync or export only Thunderbird account settings

Tags: sync, thunderbird, imap

There are many (old and not so old) topics about this, but they all deal with synchronizing the whole Thunderbird profile across computers.

I am not interested in that, **I just want a nice way to synchronize or export only the (accounts) configuration**. (all of my accounts are IMAP based, and I can redownload emails from the server without hassles.)

Please, don't tell me to synchronize the whole profile folder. It is 3.65GB, and I just want to recover my accounts config. Information-wise it should only be a few KBs.

Answers related to this question but which do not answer it

- [How do I sync Thunderbird across two computers?](https://superuser.com/questions/328091/how-do-i-sync-thunderbird-across-two-computers)
- [Is there a simple way to synchronize Thunderbird across machines?](https://superuser.com/questions/316327/is-there-a-simple-way-to-synchronize-thunderbird-across-machines)

Actually there is an answer in the question "[Merge/synchronize two Thunderbird installations](https://superuser.com/questions/935122/merge-synchronize-two-thunderbird-installations)" which mentions prefs.js but it isn't clear, and the answerer himself says, "it may even be longer than to re-enter all settings manually.
"

Comment: I'm a bit amazed there is no simple "export account" feature built-in to Thunderbird?! (There does not appear to be AFAICS.) Maybe there is a plugin available that adds this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try [MozBackup](http://ccm.net/download/download-2409-mozbackup), which allows you to selectively backup and restore settings, as well as contacts, history etc. (as well as mail, if you wish).

[Accountex](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-US/thunderbird/addon/accountex/?src=search) also professes to do what you want (*caveat*: I have not used it, and it has a two-of-five star rating).

See [*Mozilla Thunderbird - Backup your settings*](http://ccm.net/faq/1911-mozilla-thunderbird-backup-your-settings) for other suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

You can copy these 3 files in the new profile folders to restore the accounts (if you only copy pref.js the password won't be restore that's why you need the 2 other files):

```
prefs.js
logins.json
key4.db
```

On windows, they are in the thunderbird profile folder:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\xxxxxx.default-release
```

Comment: I love you. This should be the highest voted answer on the internet